# how to terminate running m-file from command line and return to command line in Matlab

Tags: matlab

What I want is simple; terminate a loop in a running m file from command line in matlab and return to command line. A matlab function that detects non-pressing of a key in a limited time will also do.

Comment: The usual interrupt signal of ctrl-c works when m-files are running. However, if compiled code is running, you'll have to wait for it to finish.

Comment: Ctrl C also works with compiled code, but the result is more drastic. You can catch ctrl-C inside MATLAB and clean up. When compiled, and running in the command line, you are dumped out of the program without any chance to clean up first.

Comment: You could also test for a particular key press (say 'A', for abort) at your command line prompt. MATLAB does not have a timeout on prompts for user input, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This will stop MATLAB and return back to the command line.